# How do I get elements from a Django Queryset starting from a specific position?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset in a Python/Django project:

```
articles = ArticlePage.objects.live().order_by('-date')
```

If I wanted to get only the first 50 elements I'd do:

```
articles[:50]
```

But also I need to get elements **from position 5**, this is to ignore the first 4 elements.

I was expecting it to have something like `articles[5:][:50]` but I can't seem to find anything like that in the docs.

*Is there any way to achieve this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's standard Python slice notation, so `articles[5:50]`. Behind the scenes it's implemented with OFFSET and LIMIT in the database query.